# USB hub that resolves mouse/keyboard stutter

Tags: usb, hub, power

Please use baby language that doesn't include any technical terms because I'm very lost :)

My wireless mouse and keyboard stutter when connected via a hub to my laptop (which has only 2 usb ports), and when a third thing is plugged in (such as a charger or usb) they stutter to the point of not working.

Is the problem here the hub or the laptop (Lenovo Thinkbook G2 ITL)?

I found a [usb hub](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07PY87TBD/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_v2neEb1PDH2W3) that seems like it might help from [Trying to find a USB-C to ~4x USB-A hub that is fully powered from upstream power delivery](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/12643) - is this a potential solution for my problem? (I can't get my head around all the technical jargon.)

In total, **what do I need to look for in a usb hub that will guarantee my peripherals to work?** I really don't want to have to plug in to the mains socket if I can help it.

Please help!

Comment: There could be a couple different causes, it's hard to figure out why it's stuttering with the info you have given. One possibility is that the hub doesn't have enough power for 3 devices and that causes the wireless connection to drop. Another possibility is that the "third thing" you plug in is using too much bandwidth and not giving the mouse and keyboard a chance to talk. Is your existing hub USB 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

- you are using wireless (bluetooth) keyboard [and mouse] in addition to the existing keyboard/mouse **on the laptop**
- I would first disconnect the wireless keyboard AND mouse and use just those as built in on the laptop; and observe if there is no *stutter*.  If the problem persists then it is not to do with the wireless kybd/mouse it's something to do with your laptop hardware and/or operating system.
- if you prefer the size & feel of a traditional keyboard and traditional mouse rather than what's on the laptop, first get a regular USB **wired** keyboard and separate USB **wired** mouse; they will have USB-A connections.  You need two USB-A female ports on the laptop to accommodate that, which you say you have.  If the *stutter* problem doesn't happen this way then good...
- if you want to free up a usb-A female port on the laptop since you only have two, then get a cheap usb hub, does not need to be powered for just a keyboard and mouse.  see link below, less than $10.

it's likely the wireless/bluetooth keyboard/mouse is your problem, they can often act flakey, for a number of reasons the simplest it could just be junk.  So a usb hub is not some magical device that will not resolve such problems when the problem is either with the wireless (bluetooth) transmission between the kybd or mouse and the bluetooth dongle plugged in on one of the laptop usb ports, or any of that hardware.  The cost of a traditional wired keyboard and wired mouse is minimal, yeah not as convenient as having no wires but way more problem free.  With all the bluetooth stuff these days, it could be other bluetooth devices in the area causing minor interference with your bluetooth'd keyboard/mouse.

I have many of these and they work well, anything that's similar would be fine, connect your wired keyboard and wired mouse to this then this hub to your laptop:

$9 `SABRENT 4-Port USB 2.0 Data Hub with Individual LED lit Power Switches [Charging NOT Supported] for Mac & PC (HB-UMLS)`

[https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-4-Port-Individual-Switches-HB-UMLS/dp/B00BWF5U0M/ref=sr_1_4?crid=LLYNC3OIRIXS&keywords=usb+hub&qid=1662492969&sprefix=usb+hub%2Caps%2C88&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BWF5U0M)